# I cannot find the defaultLayout in VUE 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I saw that in Vue 2 you have a folder **/layouts** and inside, a default template, that is rendered for every vue view.

In vue 3, i didn't see that folder, i tried to research more, and i find that we have **.nuxt/** folder, and inside the **/layouts** folder, but that layot, its override for a empty page, every time i run *npm run dev*

Can somebody tell me how i can make to have a default Layout for my views? with my css, headers, navbar.. etc

Thanks

Comment: In Nuxt3, you need to create that one yourself. https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts

Comment: Don't touch to `.nuxt`, it is used for cache purpose and will indeed be always overridden when you change a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nuxt 3, you need to create the `layouts` folder.

To add a default layout:

1. Create `layouts` folder to the root of your nuxt 3 app (path: /layouts).
2. Create a `default.vue` (path: /layouts/default.vue).
3. Add your code to your default layout.

To use the default layout in your app/page:

```
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    some page content
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

Reference: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/layouts